# Adding a key sequence as a command in Vim

Tags: vim

I wanted a quick way to delete all the lines in a buffer, so I added this to my .vimrc

```
if !exists(“:Dall”)
    command Dall ggdG
endif
```

However, when I try to run it, I get an error that “ggdG” is not an editor command.

What is the mistake I am making?

Comment: If you have that literally as shown, with curly quotes, I think your `exists` test will not be valid. You should use regular ASCII double-quote (`"`).

Comment: @DanLowe Safari smart quoting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a command that way, it's as though you're typing the new command into the command bar. So when you execute `:Dall`, it becomes the equivalent of typing `:ggdG`, which is obviously not a valid command.

What you want to do instead is have that execute in normal mode. You can make your command do that be using the `normal` command, like this:

```
command Dall normal ggdG
```